# How execute NodeJS code in order? Mysql insertId cannot be properly added in the table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to use Promise and Then. I try to input the data for two foreign keys' table and get the insertId for the table that contains the sole two constaints. I think I did it orderly in the code, but I don't know why it still show the insertId still 0. Here is my code:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'password',
    database: 'filmgogoApplicants'
});

app.post('/submit',(req, res) => {
let sql0 ="INSERT INTO applicantsInfo SET ?";
let sql11 = "INSERT INTO proSkillInfo SET ?";
let sql22 = "INSERT INTO applicant SET ?";

let applicantInfoData = {
            chineseName: req.body.chineseName, 
            englishName: req.body.englishName, 
            cellPhone: req.body.cellPhone, 
            emailAddress: req.body.emailAddress
        }

let proSkillInfoData = {
    photography: 1,
    design: 1,
    writing: 1
}

const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
    var applicantInfoInsertId = 0;
    var proSkillInfoInsertId = 0;

    if(applicantInfoInsertId == 0 && proSkillInfoInsertId == 0) {    
        let query0 = connection.query(sql0, applicantInfoData,(err, results, ) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("applicantInfoData is stored for sql");
            applicantInfoInsertId = results.insertId;
            console.log(applicantInfoInsertId);
         })

        let query1 = connection.query(sql11, proSkillInfoData,(err, results) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log("proSkillInfo is stored for sql");
            proSkillInfoInsertId = results.insertId;
            console.log(proSkillInfoInsertId);
        })

        let applicantData = {
            applicantsInfoID: proSkillInfoInsertId,
            proSkillID: applicantInfoInsertId
        }

        resolve (applicantData);
    } else {    
        reject(error);  
    }
});

myPromise.then((message) => {

    let query2 = connection.query(sql22, message,(err, results) =>{
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log("applicant data is stored for sql");
        res.redirect('/success');
     })
})

})
```

the error info is below

errno: 1452,
sqlMessage: 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`filmgogoApplicants`.`applicant`, CONSTRAINT `proSkillID` FOREIGN KEY (`proSkillID`) REFERENCES `proSkillInfo` (`proSkillID`))',
sqlState: '23000',
index: 0,
sql: 'INSERT INTO applicant SET `applicantsInfoID` = 0, `proSkillID` = 0'
}

I think I already set applicantsInfoID and proSkillID to the insertId. How come they are still 0??

[A picture of MySQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEQ0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

For async work with database I would suggest an [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) like [Sequelize](https://sequelize.org/) in order to manage the connection and data transfer using models or [Bluebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird) which creates some promises that waits for responses from the database. Your error comes because you're not handling properly the insertion for you tables relationship. Using the ORM would help alot